# Can't get Injected Ember Service from Ember Controller - But works on models & adapters

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm running into an issue with an Ember CLI project where I can't get an injected ember service from a controller action function.

The really strange thing is that this totally works on my models and custom adapters:

the controller:

```js
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  node: Ember.inject.service(),

  azureStorage: Ember.computed.alias('node.azureStorage'),

  actions: {

    myAction: function () {
      // this returns null
      var x = this.get('azureStorage');
    }
  }
});

// The service code (azureStorage and fs are NOT null)

if (window.requireNode) {
    azureStorage = window.requireNode('azure-storage');
    fs = window.requireNode('fs');
}
export default Ember.Service.extend({
    azureStorage: azureStorage,
    fs: fs,
    getActiveAccount: function (store) {
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var accounts = store.all('account'),
                length = accounts.get('length'),
                i = 0;
            accounts.forEach(function (account) {
                if (account.get('active') === true) {
                    return Ember.run(null, resolve, account);
                }
                i += 1;
                if (i >= length) {
                    return Ember.run(null, reject, 'could not find any active accounts');
                }
            });
        });
    }
});



// the controller test code

var controller = this.subject();
controller.send('myAction');
```

I would have expected this to return the service and the azureStorage object. On my models & adapters the same pattern works just fine:

```js
export default DS.Adapter.extend({
    serializer: serializer.create(),
    node: Ember.inject.service(),
    azureStorage: Ember.computed.alias('node.azureStorage'),
    findQuery: function () {
      // this returns the value correctly
      var x = this.get('azureStorage');
    }
});
```

Any reason this would work on models & adapters but NOT on a controller?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the `Ember.inject.service()` pattern, but is there a reason you're not using the pattern outlined in http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/ ?

Also, why are you injecting `node` and `azureStorage` into the controller if you've already abstracted them into an adapter?  You should just be using `this.store.find('whatever', 123)` from the controller to get your data.  If your azureStore is different than your normal Ember Data store, then you should create a new store and register it with the application's container.  If you inject it in your controller, you can access it with `this.azureStore`, or alternatively `this.container.lookup('store:azure')`.

Also, not a good practice to start injecting stuff into your models.  I would really take a look at the Ember-friendly ways of doing service/dependency injection, because this doesn't look very elegant and you're duplicating a lot of code to get access to something you already have.